# Programação em PHP com beagle bone , como receber uma variavel

Tags: php, c, webserver

Estou fazendo um web server usando a Beaglebone black, gostaria de saber como receber uma variavel no web server e acessa-la localmente em um programa C na beaglebone .

Comment: PODE ser que tenha interpretado sua pergunta de forma errada por isso um comentario, mas você pode tentar usar as funções  [system](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.system.php) ou [exec](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php) e com elas chamar via PHP seu programa em C algo como `exec("d:/programa.exe $valor1 $valor2", $output); print_r($output);`

Comment: Se estás a usar [CGI](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/handouts/cgi.html), o teu programa recebe valores através do *environment*.